# Performing an operation without doing the evaluation

Tags: haskell, eval

Suppose we have a function like this:

```
f:Int->Int
```

which gives us a modified output based on the input.

My question is, is there anyway I can write this function,so that no evaluation is done on the input? For instance consider the following expected input and output:

**Input**: 3+2/1+90

**Output**: 3+2/1+90+2

**[Edit]**
I had heard about Haskell's lazy evaluation, but I just realized that it's exactly what I wanted and as long as I don't call the print, actually no evaluation is done in the parse tree.

Comment: Normally no evaluation will be done, Haskell uses lazy evaluation: only when necesseray parts of the generated syntax tree will be evaluated...

Comment: Well sounds like it evaluates the input first,in my example. I want to know if there's a way to force lazy evaluation.

Comment: No well + is syntactical sugar, right? So basically it will store the element interally as `+(+(+(3,/(2,1),90),2)`. Only when you want to output it, the Haskell execution environment will notice that 3+2/1+90+2 isn't a scalar. So it will start calculating: and it will see the first argument of `+(+(+(3,/(2,1),90),2)` isn't a scalar either... After a long number of evaluations the scalar is calculated and returned...

Comment: Do you mean to *symbolically* evaluate the expression? I.e. your type is `f :: AST  -> AST`

Comment: @CommuSoft Does it perform evaluation inside-out? I always assumed it reduced from the outside and inwards, as deep as it has to. (Which in this case is all the way, but not always.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell things are always lazy, so you're always going to have a computation equivalent to `3+2/1+90+2` but when you ask for the printed version, you'll evaluate it.

You can do stuff like this

```
f x = x + 2

main = do
  let x = f (error "Kaboom!!")
  print 1
```

And run it just fine, but trying to print it will force evaluation.

```
main = do
   let x = f (error "Kaboom!!")
   print x
```

Which will error. The story has some subtleties with how much/when things are evaluated, but that's the gist of it.

At this point, Haskell has lost all ability to "pretty print" a computation, all of the information has been compiled away into explicit closures and other ugliness. If you want to watch to computation build up, there is a kinda fun trick

```
newtype TraceableNum = Trace { runTrace :: String }

instance Num TraceableNum where
   (Trace a) + (Trace b) = Trace $ "(" ++ a ++ " + " ++ b ++ ")"
   (Trace a) - (Trace b) = Trace $ "(" ++ a ++ " - " ++ b ++ ")"
   (Trace a) * (Trace b) = Trace $ "(" ++ a ++ " * " ++ b ++ ")"
   abs (Trace a) = Trace $ "abs(" ++ a ++ ")"
   signum (Trace a) = Trace $ "signum(" ++ a ++ ")"
   fromInteger = Trace . show

 main = print . runTrace $ 1 + 4 * 7
```

Daniel Wagner pointed out if you want to continue with this idea: [simple-reflect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect)

Comment: Thank you, can I define a traceable bool as well? since I tried to do the same with && and || operators and it told me that those are not (visible) methods of Num class. I also used Enum class and it didn't help.

Comment: Given your suggestion at the end, you should definitely point at [simple-reflect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/simple-reflect).

Comment: Hey daniel, I installed that package and tried to use it.I read the documentation and I'm not sure if I should derive from simpleReflect class or anything else? Have you ever used it?

Comment: @ye9ane The documentation includes several examples. Did you try them? Also, be sure to click the link to the "home page" -- it's a blog post with a very clear explanation of this trick.

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks for the link, I'm going to add it to the question body proper